# execute command in gnome-terminal using python

Tags: python, command-line, gnome-terminal

I am trying to open one file from gnome-terminal using python. But I am not able to do it.It is just opening terminal and not opening file.
I have tried like:

```
import os
os.system('gnome-terminal --working-directory = "folder_path" + "[-e, --command=" kate aaa.txt""')
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `+ "[-e, --command=" kate aaa.txt""`, `gnome-terminal` doesn't know how to parse this `+ "[` and `""`, according to the manual, `-e` and `--command` mean the same thing:

```bash
man gnome-terminal

...

       --command, -e=COMMAND
           Split the argument to this option into a program and arguments in the same way a shell
           would, and execute the resulting command-line inside the terminal.

           This option is deprecated. Instead, use -- to terminate the options, and put the program
           and arguments to execute after it: for example, instead of gnome-terminal -e "python3 -q",
           prefer to use gnome-terminal -- python3 -q.

           Note that the COMMAND is not run via a shell: it is split into words and executed as a
           program. If shell syntax is required, use the form gnome-terminal -- sh -c '...'.
```

This works for me in `Archlinux`:

```py
import os
os.system('gnome-terminal --working-directory = /home/ramsay --command="kate 
os"')
```